# Can't read Int from other class

Tags: java, variables, external

I have two files:

The first is:

```
public class MyClass1 {

    static int glZahl = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass1 myLocalObj = new MyClass1();
        myLocalObj.localMeth();     

        OtherClass myExtObj = new OtherClass();
        myExtObj.extMeth();
        myExtObj.exZahl;
    } 
    public static void localMeth(){
        System.out.println("Ausgabe aus localMeth()");
    }
```

The 2nd file is :

```
public class OtherClass {

   static int exZahl = 5;

   static int x = 5;

   public static void extMeth(){

      System.out.println("Ausgabe aus ext. Methode aus pck1.OtherClass (Meth. system.out)");

      System.out.println("Ausgabe aus ext. Methode aus pck1.OtherClass, OtherClass.class static int = " + exZahl);

}
```

In the shell created MyClass.class via

```
$ javac -d MyClass.java
$ javac -d OtherClass.java
```

I try to System.out.println **exZahl** from **OtherClass.class**

I do get this error message:

```
$ java MyClass.java

MyClass1.java:50: error: not a statement
        myExtObj.exZahl;
                ^
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

I figure I do some sort of basic mistake.

Comment: Besides that you should be careful using statics, you need to do something with `myExtObj.exZahl`. E.g. `System.out.println(myExtObj.exZahl);`

Comment: Well, what do you expect that statement to *do*? You're referring to the field (admittedly non-ideally - you're accessing a *static* field as if it were an *instance* field - it would be better to write `OtherClass.exZahl`) but you're not saying what you want to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hm I thought just doing

```
myExtObj.exZahl;
```

would work. Calling the object, concatinate the var.

As CannedMoose3 mengioned,

```
System.out.println("ext. output " + myExtObj.exZahl);
```

works.

Thank you guys for fast helping hands :)